# What play do Draper and Megan see?

Tags: mad-men

Mad Men Season 5 episode 9, "Christmas Waltz": Don Draper and his wife see a play. The stage is gray with blocks, the cast's clothes are gray too.

Was it real? What was the name of the play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it was a real play. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Waltz_%28Mad_Men%29):

> Megan (Jessica Paré) and Don watch the play **[America Hurrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_Hurrah)**, in which a character rants against TV advertisements. After the play, they argue about its negative portrayal of advertising.

It was a satirical play that premiered in 1966. You can also see the playbill in this clip, around 0:30:

Comment: Thanks Walt for the quick response. I did not think to read wikipedia could help at all. But you see.. :|